# Is there a way to quote other posters?

Tags: support

I'm used to being able to quote responses from other people on another website.  I want to know if there is a way to quote other people's posts that you want to respond to.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, maybe with an example of what you want to do?  Of course you can quote things from this website on other websites.  You can also link to any individual post.  But I do not know what you are asking.

Comment: This is not a discussion site, so what you want is in fact almost discouraged!

Comment: There is always "copy and paste".

Comment: And after pasting, please select the pasted material and click on the double quotation mark in the editor toolbar to automatically make it "quoted".

Comment: ...and if there's formatting in the text you want to quote, click "edit" and copy-paste from there.  (Tip: use a middle-click to open the edit form into a new tab.)